# iOS 10: UIImagePickerViewController Can Not Set Flash Mode

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, ios10, camera-flash

I am working on creating custom controls for my `UIImagePickerViewController`. I have the default flash setting set to `.off` and I want to switch between on and off.

But I'm having a lot of trouble getting the `UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashMode` to toggle from on to off. This should seemingly be a very easy thing to set. But I have been trying and I can not get the following to change the flash mode, it just stays in the `.off` mode.

```
func didTapFlashButton() -> Bool {
    if let picker = mediaPicker {
        if picker.cameraFlashMode == .on || picker.cameraFlashMode == .auto {
            picker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashMode.off
            return false
        }
        else {
            picker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashMode.on
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Why is this not updating the flash mode on my `UIImagePickerController`?

---

**EDIT** (answer to comment)

Yes I have checked if the code executes and it always executes the `else` block to set it to `.on`. So the `UIImagePickerController` correctly acknowledges that the default flash mode I set is `.false` (verified via print statement).

But, whenever I tap the button to change flash mode to `.on` the flash never works. This meaning it never updated the flash mode on the `UIImagePickerController`.

I don't know why this isn't working and I can't find any other way to set the flash mode other than what I'm doing.

Comment: Have you checked that your code is actually executed? Does `mediaPicker` contain the right value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one actually made me feel kind of stupid. Shortly after posting this question I realized that the device I was testing on did not have flash capabilities. What you should do if you are using flash mode is to first ask the `UIImagePickerController` class if the device is able to use flash in the first place. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619118-isflashavailable).